# Regex for WebURL of a webpage (both internal and external links)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to fetch all the a href urls from a webpage
Foreg: example.htm
       https://www.myexample.com/awards-recognition.htm">

All the urls should be fetched although its starting with http|https not.

I tried following Regex: `@"<(a).*?href=(""|')(.+?)(""|').*?>"`
but not getting the output as expected.

Can anyone help in defining regular expression for above scenario?

Comment: Try this regex: `"<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>.*?</a>"`

Comment: I need all url from a href tag only.

Comment: Also, Link can be in any format abc.htm or https://.... any

Comment: I think you just need to search for `href=[\"|\'].*?[\"|\']`